# SQL query with multiple excludes not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to extract accounts that owe $25 or more and have been sent to collections, but I need to exclude accounts which have certain stopID blocks on them. I'm getting about a 70% success rate with the query I've written, but it still includes many of the records that have the StopID's on the exclusion statement. I'm not sure which direction to go from here - any suggestions?

```
select DISTINCT 
        Polaris.Patrons.Barcode as BARCODE,
        Polaris.PatronRegistration.NameLast AS [LAST NAME],
        Polaris.PatronRegistration.NameFirst AS [FIRST NAME],
        Polaris.PatronRegistration.NameMiddle AS [MIDDLE NAME],
        cast(Patrons.ChargesAmount as decimal(22,2)) AS AMOUNT,
        Polaris.Addresses.StreetOne AS ADDRESS,
        Polaris.PostalCodes.City AS CITY,
        Polaris.PostalCodes.State AS STATE,
        Polaris.PostalCodes.PostalCode AS ZIP,
        Cast (PatronRegistration.Birthdate AS DATE) AS DOB                    
from Polaris.PatronRegistration TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(6 PERCENT) inner join 
        Polaris.Patrons on PatronRegistration.PatronID = Polaris.Patrons.PatronID  left join 
        Polaris.PatronAddresses on PatronRegistration.PatronID = PatronAddresses.PatronID   left join 
        Polaris.Addresses on PatronAddresses.AddressID = Polaris.Addresses.AddressID    left join 
        Polaris.PostalCodes ON Polaris.Addresses.PostalCodeID = Polaris.PostalCodes.PostalCodeID  left outer join 
        Polaris.PatronStops ON Polaris.Patrons.PatronID = Polaris.PatronStops.PatronID left outer join 
        Polaris.PatronStopDescriptions ON Polaris.PatronStops.PatronStopID = Polaris.PatronStopDescriptions.PatronStopID  
where Patrons.OrganizationID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)  --All Organizations
        and Patrons.PatronCodeID in (1,2,4,5,6,8,9,14,15)  --All patron types except FOL,Minor,Staff,Volunteer,NRC,WWR,Minor E-Card
        and Patrons.ChargesAmount >= 25.00  --Accounts with balance of $25 or more
        and Patrons.SystemBlocks in (1024)  --Accounts have been sent to Collections block
        and NOT (Polaris.PatronStops.PatronStopID in (7,13,14,15,16)) --Accounts contain any of these StopID codes
order by NameLast asc,NameFirst asc,NameMiddle asc
```

Comment: If you remove the `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(6 PERCENT)`, do you still experience the problem?